# BASH, getopts to pass arguments as well as read file line by line

Tags: bash, getopts

In my current script I use getopts to pass options settings, then read the files line by line

```
#! /bin/bash

GetA=0
GetB=0

while getopts "ab:c:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
    a) 
       GetA=1
       echo "-a get option a"
       ;;
    b)
       GetB=1
       echo "-b get option b"
       ;;
    c)
       c=${OPTARG}
       ;;
    esac
done

shift "$((OPTIND -l ))"


while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo $line
    echo "GetA is " $GetA 
    echo "GetB is " $GetB 
    echo "c is " $c
done
```

Now, if run this script with following command lines:

```
testscript.sh -ab -c 10 somefile.txt
```

Expected result:

```
$ line1 from somefile.txt
  GetA is 1
  GetB is 1
  c is 10
```

However, an error is given:

```
/testscript.sh: line number: No such file or directory
```

EDIT 7/13/2016: 
    There is an extra ':' after b, after removing it, the script no longer gives error.

```
while getopts "ab:c:" opt; do
```

Corrected:

```
while getopts "abc:" opt; do
```

Comment: You probably want a `;;` terminating your `b)` case. And your `b:` definition expects an argument, but your example command line doesn't pass one.

Comment: you are correct. Optoin b is not suppose to have ':' behind it. I fixed it and now the problem has went away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read` reads from standard input, not the command line argument. Either explicitly specify the file to read from:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do  # Assume the file ends with a newline
    ...
done < "$1"
```

or feed the file to your script with input redirection:

```
testscript.sh -ab -c 10 < somefile.txt
```